# How to Add Another Item in A List That's A Value for a Dictionary if the Key has already been used

Tags: python, dictionary

Okay, so to preface this this uses File Input and Output which I super have no idea what I'm doing with. So, basically, I have a data file that's like
name, date, time
name, date, time
name, date, time
etc.
With each value being a string.
And right now I have it transferring into a dictionary that's like {"name1": ["time1, date1"], "name2": ["time2, date2"], "name3": ["time3, date3"]}
The issue is that if in the file there's a repeat name, I want it to append to the dictionary like
"name1": ["time1, date1", "time4, date4"]
But I'm having a lot of issues.
The first bit of the code is just to get the names and dates in the way I want them to be and it's probably inefficient but I also don't really care.
The loop probably doesn't make any sense since I've been playing around with it so much, but I'm just at a loss now.
Also my formatting probably isn't great, sorry. I really have no clue what I'm doing with that.

datafile.txt:

```
James, Blake, 10:22:00, 09/5/2021
Donald, Yun, 10:22:03, 09/5/2021
Rain, Cloud, 10:22:04, 09/5/2021
Thunder, Storm, 10:22:07, 09/5/2021
Blue, Sky, 10:22:09, 09/5/2021
Green, Grass, 10:22:16, 09/5/2021
Starry, Night, 10:22:18, 09/5/2021
James, Blake, 10:22:03, 09/6/2021
```

code file:

```
a = {}
with open("datafile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(", ")
        line[0:2] = [", ".join(line[0:2])]
        line[1:] = [", ".join(line[1:])]

        for i in range(1):
            if line[i] in a:
                a[line[i]].append(line[1])
            else:
                a[line[i]] = [line[1]]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tricky structure of your data file is tripping you up.  I suggest destructuring the 4 fields into 4 named variables to make it easier to keep them straight:

```
a = {}
with open("datafile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        fname, lname, time, date = line.strip().split(", ")
        a.setdefault(f"{fname}, {lname}", []).append(f"{time}, {date}")
print(a)
```

```
{'James, Blake': ['10:22:00, 09/5/2021', '10:22:03, 09/6/2021'], 'Donald, Yun': ['10:22:03, 09/5/2021'], 'Rain, Cloud': ['10:22:04, 09/5/2021'], 'Thunder, Storm': ['10:22:07, 09/5/2021'], 'Blue, Sky': ['10:22:09, 09/5/2021'], 'Green, Grass': ['10:22:16, 09/5/2021'], 'Starry, Night': ['10:22:18, 09/5/2021']}
```

If you have the ability to change the format of your data file, that'd make things significantly easier -- for example, if you just used standard CSV formatting (quoting the fields that contain a delimiter) the file would look like:

```
"James, Blake","10:22:00, 09/5/2021"
"Donald, Yun","10:22:03, 09/5/2021"
"Rain, Cloud","10:22:04, 09/5/2021"
"Thunder, Storm","10:22:07, 09/5/2021"
"Blue, Sky","10:22:09, 09/5/2021"
"Green, Grass","10:22:16, 09/5/2021"
"Starry, Night","10:22:18, 09/5/2021"
"James, Blake","10:22:03, 09/6/2021"
```

and then your code wouldn't need to deal with parsing the line into four fields and then re-combining them into two:

```
import csv

a = {}
with open("datafile.txt") as f:
    for name, time_date in csv.reader(f):
        a.setdefault(name, []).append(time_date)
            
print(a)
```